# how to create a mask for a given data type?

Tags: c++, c

I have an integer, whose sizeof will be determined at run time. Now, I want to use this for masking based on its size.

For example, if size of int is 2 bytes, then the mask value is 0xFF. If the size of integer is 4bytes, then the mask value is 0xFFFF.How can I do so? Also, finally I want to extract the Most Significant nibble from a number. How can I do so in a smart way?

Comment: `0xff` takes one, not two, bytes.

Comment: For the mask value, simply use `UINT_MAX` (assuming it's meant to actually be 0xFFFF for 2 bytes and 0xFFFFFFFF for 4 bytes).

Comment: You can do `(1ul << (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)) - 1` in order to mask an `int` (but why would you do that?) -- as to the MSN, it's `number >> (sizeof(number) * CHAR_BIT - 4)`.

Comment: @Yuushi rather `UINT_MAX`, no? A 16-bit `INT_MAX` would be 0x7FFF.

Comment: @H2CO3 Yep, my bad. Fixed. Also, `(1ul << (sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT)) - 1` would be UB on any playform where `sizeof(unsigned long) == sizeof(int)` (eg if they were both 4 bytes) as you'd be left shifting a 32 bit value by 32.

Comment: @Yuushi Yup, correct. But then you can check for that using `sizeof` and back up to `-1` instead. But having a second look at it, it's just unnecessary complexity, `UINT_MAX` is better.

Comment: The size of an integer is *not* determined at runtime. It's already known at compile time.

Comment: Nibbles you say half of int or 4-bit?

Answer (score 0):

//assuming you take `signed int`

`0XFFFFFFFF == -1` (in 4byte int machine)

`0XFFFF == -1` (in 2byte int machine)

`0XFF == -1` (in 1byte in machine which is not there anymore)

so at runtime even if size increases so does your  variable assigned to -1.

To calaculate MSB `x` being your number

```
if( ( (0 | 1) << sizeof(int) & x) > 0)
    //MSB is 1
else 
    // MSB is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

unsigned Most_Significant_nibble(int number){
    int numOfHalfBit = sizeof(number) * CHAR_BIT / 2;
    unsigned num = number, mask = (1u << numOfHalfBit)-1;
    return (num >> numOfHalfBit) & mask;
}

int main(void){
    int n = 0x87654321;//size of int is 4
    unsigned msn = Most_Significant_nibble(n);
    printf("%#x\n", msn);//0x8765
    return 0;
}
```